# what apps are running?

Tags: processes

A few months back I started developing an app that read incoming sms messages and saved them in a db.

A few days ago I went to revisit the app and had a quick look in the db where I discovered the app was still recording my texts!?!

I can't find any mention of my app running on the android apps option under settings or in advanced task killer.

How can I find out if it's running or not? It's bizarre!

Comment: Being rather development related, this question IMHO is better fitted on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Izzy I agree, however I started out with best intentions of just finding out a list of apps

Comment: Russ, I never implied bad intentions! But the name of this site is too often misunderstood to be related to Android *development* (which it is not, see our [FAQ]). So most OT questions are asked unaware of that, and we simply give a friendly hint. -- Looks like your accepted answer also proves the direction :)

Comment: Sorry, hope my comment didn't come across rude, I meant to agree with you. I was originally hoping for some option somewhere in the os that listed all apps. Thanks again

Comment: Don't worry, I understood this ;)

Comment: `Settings > Apps` then swipe left to see the list of running apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar incidence, in my case i left a service open. Please check if any service related, is open ?

To check you can use,
[This link from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523718/how-to-check-all-the-running-services-in-android)

Comment: I didn't do anything with a service. Being told on SO that if I use a broadcast receiver, then it will continually act until uninstalled even if the app isn't running, though I find this very odd

Comment: Yes, even broadcast receiver has similar behavior, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301111/android-application-is-still-working-after-exit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096246/set-broadcastreceiver-to-be-inactive will help for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I don't fully understand how broadcast receivers work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040651/is-my-app-still-running